# Passing input to Ant's <exec> task

Tags: ant

I have an Ant script running a standard -task after taking in an inputed password:

```
<input message="Password:" addproperty="password">
<handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
</input>

<exec executable="/bin/sh" input="${password}" failonerror="true">
    <arg line='-c "myScript.sh"' />
</exec>
```

The script myScript.sh prompts the user for a password, and, it was my understanding that from the Ant documentation that *input* is supposed relay input into whatever the `<exec>` task is executing, but instead I get (for entering the password foobar)

```
[exec] Failed to open /usr/local/foobar
```

which is followed by a stack trace from my script complaining about an incorrect password...so obviously I've understood the documentation wrong. Does anybody know how to handle prompted input from external scripts in Ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input="${password}"
```

This will try to read from the file ${password} and send the contents into your script. Try using:

```
inputstring="${password}"
```

instead. This will send the string itself instead of treating it like a filename

Comment: Let me highlight the importance of using '-c "/your/command"' in the <arg> element and set the "executable" attribute of the <exec> element to "/bin/sh".